# How to codesign and enable the hardened runtime for a 3rd-party CLI on Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, codesign, osx-gatekeeper

My project needs the Ghostscript to do lots of tasks, so I have added the gs CLI tool into my project resource. However when I tried to notarize the project application, Xcode shows me this:

[image]

I assume that might because the ghostscript portable CLI is a 3rd-party program from the internet and which doesn't have a codesign, also it has not been enabled the hardened runtime. On the latest MacOS Mojave I have to notarize applications to avoid the gatekeeper shows warnings during the user opens the DMG file. But it seems the notarizing is hard to pass if the application contains a 3rd-party CLI.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the solution finally. Sign the CLI this way:

```
codesign --force --options runtime --sign "Developer ID Application: COMPANYNAME" ./CLITool
```

Then I successfully archived the Application and uploaded to Apple to notarize.

Comment: How does this fullfil the hardening requirements?

Comment: I think it would be "--options runtime". Since I signed the command tool by this, it works.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  Where did you find this information/parameter(s)?  I assume it will coincide with this? https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/en.lproj/Art/ca_enablehardenedruntime.png

Comment: @tresf https://forum.xojo.com/49408-10-14-hardened-runtime-and-app-notarization/0

Comment: Adding "--options runtime" to codesign solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: My app's mac executable developed via maven (java project). Then I used codesign command with `--option=runtime` for notarization. But if I sign with `--option=runtime`my app doesn't run. 
Showing `The [APP_NAME] executable launcher was unable to locate its 
companion shared library.`

Answer (score 3):

The enable hardened runtime is achieved via `--options runtime`.

I found [this guide](https://lessons.livecode.com/m/4071/l/1122100-codesigning-and-notarizing-your-lc-standalone-for-distribution-outside-the-mac-appstore) to be very helpful with the notarization and code signing process for app distribution outside the mac store.

I had an issue with my app crashing after enabling hardened runtime for it tho. This [comment](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4629#issuecomment-574375331) and this [other one](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4629#issuecomment-583785114) helped me with my issue at the time.